# Is there any way to create push ID manually in Firebase console?

Tags: firebase, firebase-realtime-database, firebase-console

In my java code I know how to create unique ID by calling `push()` method

```
DatabaseReference().child("list").push();
```

My question is:

Is there any way to do that manually in Firebase Realtime Database Console? I mean in a website?

Comment: what do you mean by this _I mean in a website?_

Comment: @PeterHaddad What I mean is the website of the Firebase. https://console.firebase.google.com

Comment: no you cannot @basaya

Comment: @PeterHaddad thank you for the clarification

Comment: no worries, but u can just write random letters if you want

Comment: My FirebaseRecyclerView doesn't return anything if the unique ID is not created by push() method unless there is another way to make my FirebaseRecyclerView works.

Comment: nope there is not any other way, just use `push()` only way

Comment: I used '1' as my unique ID. or should I use letter instead of number to make my FirebaseRecyclerView works?

Comment: Ok got it. thanks for the answer

Comment: check my answer below @basaya

Comment: You can perform a push using the Firebase CLI. https://firebase.google.com/docs/cli/#database_commands  I wrote a blog about it: https://firebase.googleblog.com/2017/12/read-and-write-your-realtime-database.html

Answer (score 3, accepted):

No, you cannot create a `push()` id manually in the firebase console. You can manually add random numbers/letters in the console but that wont help you later on.

You use the `push()` that generates a unique key for each new child thus preventing overriding data.

Example:

```
Users
  pushid_here
      name: userx
      age: 100
  pushid_here
      name: usery
      age: 121
```

Then when you are querying you can use `getKey()` to get the push key and be able to access the data inside of it. That is why the firebaserecyclerview you said in the comments only works with `push()`.

for more info: https://firebase.google.com/docs/database/admin/save-data#getting-the-unique-key-generated-by-push